# MAUI - Display Alert Buttons Missing/Invisible

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I recently converted out Xamarin Forms app to MAUI. One of the [many] issues I'm running into is that the display alert buttons are invisible on Android. They're still there. I can click on them. I just can't see them.

The following should generate a display with an "OK" button, but doesn't. Thoughts?

```
 public void BackupDatabase()
 {
  // Do stuf...
  DisplayAlert("Database Backup Successful", "The database has been successfully backed up.", true);
 }

 public static void DisplayAlert(string title, string message, bool forceShow = false)
 {
  if (LastMessage == message && !forceShow)
   return;

  LastMessage = message;
  Page currentPage = CurrentPage;
  if (currentPage != null)
   RunOnUiThread(() => currentPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, "OK"));
 }

 public static void RunOnUiThread(Action action) { MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => action.Invoke()); }
```

[image]

However, the display alerts works fine when running on a Windows Machine.

[image]

Update 10/21/2022:

I just noticed that the buttons on the date select popup are gone too. Ungh...

[image]

Comment: Does this happen if you make a new Maui project, and add a Display Alert to it? If not, then perhaps there is some theme/colors issue - white on white.

Comment: While creating a new app to submit some various MAUI bugs that I've run across, this bug didn't show up. So it's something in my main app... somewhere... But from the research that I've done, the alert button text coloring is immutable and can't be modified via styles. So, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I was able to bypass this entirely by replacing the default alerts with Toasts and Snackbars from the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit. These work just fine and I like them better anyway. You can find this in NuGet or download the code and build it yourself here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui

Note: there's a bug in the current version that brings Snackbars up over the on-screen navigation bar. So, I had to download the code directly as the fix has been pulled in. As soon as the fix is released, I'll switch to the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to run this down. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to explicitly declare what color the buttons should be in XAML. The buttons look to the "Primary" color declared in the Colors.xaml file in the Resources/Styles folder.

```
 <Color x:Key="Primary">#098DCD</Color>
 <Color x:Key="Secondary">#B9E0FF</Color>
 <Color x:Key="Accent">#B9E0FF</Color>
 <Color x:Key="Background">#E7F2FB</Color>
```

[image]

This is different behavior from Xamarin Forms and didn't show up until we converted the project to MAUI. We had the primary color set to white, because this is also the color that defaults to the background of the splash screen; and we wanted that white. But the splash screen *does* have an explicit field to set the background color.